# What is difference between SPContext.Current.Web.URL and SPContext.Current.Site when using SPSite object?

Tags: spcontext, spsite

```
SPSite spsite1=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.URL);

SPSite spsite2=SPContext.Current.Site;
```

What is the difference and when do we decide which one to use?

I feel both give us the site collection object.

Example: `SPWeb spweb=spsite1.RootWeb;` will mean same as `spsite2.RootWeb;`  Then why are there 2 ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPSite spsite1=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);` will give you `SPSite` object. But it will be site collection object only when `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` is that of root web. If the web object is that of a sub site then `SPSite` object won't be a site collection object. The second statement `SPSite spsite2=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site);` is wrong because there is no overload of `SPSite` which has `SPSite` as parameter.

**UPDATE**

If the intention is to get the rootweb then second is a better way of doing it as you are not instantiating a new `SPSite` object. Moreover, in the first case you will need to dispose `SPSite` object as you are creating a new one compared to second in which `SPSite` is retrieved through `SPContext` which should not be disposed explicitly.

Comment: sorry I have updated my question, does it make sense now?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Suppose we are far inside a sitecollection (say at the innermost web of the sc), then again approach 1 as well as 2 will provide same result. I would like to know then why is that there are 2 ways of doing it.

Comment: There are several ways of skinning a cat and you have to decide which way is better. `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` gives the `Url` of the site whether root or inner site and you can always create an `SPSite` object when you have the Url available. That is why you get tempted to create an SPSite object by instantiating a new one. But at the same time you have a better performing method already available `SPContext.Current.Site` which should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The both site1 and site2 returns the same site collection (SPSite) object.
By calling RootWeb property on both objects, We can get the same top-level web site (SPWeb) object.

Instruction1: SPSite spsite1=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.URL);

Process: If we are in subsite and we are calling the above code, first it get the current subsite web url and pass it to SPSite constructor to get the current Site Collection object.

Instruction2: SPSite spsite2 = SPContext.Current.Site;

Process: Now we are in subsite and we are calling the above code, which directly retrives the Site Collection object. There is no looking for web url parameter to get the SiteCollection.

Result:

spsite1.RootWeb and spsite2.RootWeb returns the same Top-Level web SPWeb object.

spsite1.OpenWeb() returns the subsite (SPWeb) object if we are in subsite.
spsite2.OpenWeb() returns the top-level site (SPWeb) object, even we are in subsite.

For the spsite1, we have to call dispose method to dispose the SPSite object. But for the spsite2, the sharepoint will take care on disposing of SPSite object.